# Weirdly high ping on direct ethernet connection?

Tags: windows-7, networking, ping

I bought new Lenovo IdeaCentre H430 pc and I'm having problem with high pings. 
Windows 7 with on-board realtek NIC. Fresh install, fully updated, drivers installed from included CD. 
When I start pinging router (direct 1Gb ethernet connection, 1 hop), pings start at <1ms (which is fine) and after a while they jump to 300-1000ms.

I loaded up live ubuntu to test if the problem might be in HW. It's not, in ubuntu pings were always <1ms.

I also noticed that when I start using connection somehow, pings go down to 1ms, but go back up when I stop using it (tested by accessing live camera feed on LAN).

Power Options set to max performance. 
I disabled Interrupt Moderation on the NIC, didn't help. 
I tested it in the safe mode with networking, same problem there.

It slows down our client-server based programs and I have no idea what's causing it. All I could google up was that disabling Interrupt Moderation would help, it didn't though. Anyone had similar problems?

tl;nr: Computer is giving high pings to router when idle and normal pings when network is under load, it slows down our software significantly.

Comment: Are you using a QoS on the router or any form of load balancing?

Comment: Hmm, didn't play with settings on router for ages, so if something is there then only the default stuff. Other computers in network don't have this problem though.

Comment: Do you use any other network monitor tools on the PC - I got an Asus PC and part of the bloatware was a network monitor - this played havoc and gave some very odd and unexpected results. Also the firewall could be at fault.

Comment: I'm not aware of something like that being installed there. I tested it in safe mode with everything off and it didn't work properly either.

Comment: Are you able to add a wireless dongle or similar - this may reduce where to investigate depending on the result.

Comment: Your client-server-based programs obviously open connections but they are slowed down, in contrast to your live camera feed. Is the ping speed improved when you are running your client-server program? Is the client-server program speed better when you are accessing your live camera feed? Do you see the same problem when you ping other machines on your network? Have you tried it with your windows firewall completely turned off?

Comment: If all fails I will try putting in my older NIC, but I think it's in the software given that under linux it worked fine. I'm not near the pc atm so I can't try now.

Comment: @Adam I can't test what ping does when running client-server program now (away from pc). I would guess it does the same as when loading web page, goes down for a while and then back up to crazy values. So idle connection doesn't help. And yes, if I access camera feed then all works fast as it should. Same problem when pinging other computers. I tried turning firewall off and going into safe mode, didn't help.

Comment: @Antriel I would keep the firewall turned off while you solve this, and as Dave Rock said, make sure the router QoS software and other stuff is off too. Try monitoring your machine with Win7 up and see what's on its ports with nmap and netstat to see if there's anything you don't recognise. You'll have to do nmap from someone else's machine or you could set up cygwin. Sorry but I don't know the windows equivalents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by installing different driver (not the one windows installed by default, nor the one included on the CD that came with the pc). Concretely driver for RTL8168E, while (as far as I can say) the actual NIC is RTL8167. It seems to work so far though.

Answer (score 1):

To gather some interesting details, it will be useful that you test the following destinations :

- you already tried to ping you router
- you should try to ping your own network card
- you should try to ping your loopback (127.0.0.1)

and tell if there is any difference. That will provide a way to tell where in the stack or in the driver is the problem, if it's not a QoS problem. Then we can start thinking again.